# c# : how to get all item url based on a keyword using FindingAPI of ebay

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am using the code below using FindingAPI of Ebay to get all items link of Ebay matching a keyword . In this case "gruen watch" is the keyword.
This code doesn't show more than 100 items link . How can I modify it to show all items link ??

**I have replaced my original appid

Program.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("link.txt");
        using (FindingServicePortTypeClient client = new FindingServicePortTypeClient())
        {

            MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("My-CustomHeader", "http://www.mycustomheader.com", "Custom Header");
            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {

                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
                HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME", "MY-APP-ID");
                httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "findItemsByKeywords");
                httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID", "EBAY-US");
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;


                FindItemsByKeywordsRequest request = new FindItemsByKeywordsRequest();
                request.keywords = "gruen watch";

                PaginationInput pagination = new PaginationInput();
                pagination.entriesPerPageSpecified = true;
                pagination.entriesPerPage = 250;
                pagination.pageNumberSpecified = true;
                pagination.pageNumber = 10;
                request.paginationInput = pagination;




                FindItemsByKeywordsResponse response = client.findItemsByKeywords(request);


                foreach (var item in response.searchResult.item)
                {

                    //Console.WriteLine(item.title);
                    tw.WriteLine(item.viewItemURL.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(item.viewItemURL.ToString());

                }


            }

        }

        tw.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

app.config is [here](http://codepad.org/ZeN9L8ZN)

here is the solution I have made :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1

{ 



class Program

{



    static void Main(string[] args)

    {



        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("1001.txt");

        using (FindingServicePortTypeClient client = new FindingServicePortTypeClient())

        {



            MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("My-CustomHeader", "http://www.mycustomheader.com", "Custom Header");

            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))

            {



                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);

                HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

                httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME", "MYAPPID");

                httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "findItemsByKeywords");

                httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID", "EBAY-US");

                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;





                FindItemsByKeywordsRequest request = new FindItemsByKeywordsRequest();



                request.keywords = "gruen watch";

                FindItemsByKeywordsResponse check = client.findItemsByKeywords(request);

                int totalEntries = check.paginationOutput.totalEntries;

                int cnt = 0;

                int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalEntries/100.00);



                bool flag = true;



                for (int curPage = 1; curPage <= totalPages; curPage++)

                {

                    PaginationInput pagination = new PaginationInput();



                    pagination.entriesPerPageSpecified = true;

                    pagination.entriesPerPage = 100;

                    pagination.pageNumberSpecified = true;

                    pagination.pageNumber = curPage;

                    request.paginationInput = pagination;



                    FindItemsByKeywordsResponse response = client.findItemsByKeywords(request);





                    foreach (var item in response.searchResult.item)

                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(item.viewItemURL.ToString());

                        tw.WriteLine(item.viewItemURL.ToString());

                    }

                }















            }



        }



        tw.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("end");

        Console.ReadKey();



    }



}



}
```

Comment: Hello guys!, I'am trying to use qmaruf's example, but compiler says FindingServicePortTypeClient could not be found. I have added using EbayServiceReference; and I have added refference to EbayServiceReference as Web Service. What might be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Solution for my question in previous comment was to add Service Refference to project with following url:   http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/Finding/latest/FindingService.wsdl

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the response returns the first page of data up to a maximum of 100 items. You can change this value with `paginationInput`.

On the [official eBay documentation for findItemsByKeywords](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/finditemsbykeywords.html), there is a section entitled **Paginating the Results** which tells you exactly what you need to know:

> Use `paginationInput` and its child elements to control which set of items matching the search criteria are returned in the result set. Use `paginationInput` to divide the returned items into subsets, or "pages," of data:
>
> **`paginationInput.entriesPerPage`** specifies the maximum number of items
>   to return for any given request
>
> **`paginationInput.pageNumber`** specifies
>   which "page" of data to return in the current call
>
> By default, the
>   response returns the first page of data up to a maximum of 100 items.
>   The following example shows how to return the second page of results,
>   with each page containing a maximum of 50 items:
>
> `...&paginationInput.pageNumber=2&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=50...`
>
> In this example, the response will contain the matching items 51 to 100, assuming there are at least 100 matching items.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use this info in that code . would you please help ??

Comment: There are fewer than 2400 "gruen watch" items on eBay right now, so page 10 (with 250 items per page) has fewer than 250 items. Change the "pageNumber" property of `pagination` to something less than 10.

Comment: Got it .  If total matched item is N , there will be N/100 pages . I need to get all those pages to get all item . Am I right??But how can I find total number of matching item ??If i use paginatiooutput.totalentries , it shows 0

Comment: When do you read `paginationoutput.totalentries`?

Comment: :) I have solved the problem . code edited